# Split line on 3 with php and put results into different variables

Tags: split, cut

Helllo, I faced a problem with text editing with php. I have a line

```
$line = "Knock, knock. Who's there? Beak. Beak who? Because I'M Batman"
```

I want to split it on three variables

```
$split1 = "Knock, knock. Who's there?";
$split2 = "Beak. Beak who? Because I'M";
$split3 = "Batman!";
```

With wordwrap function I can add breaks to  the line to make it look how I want, but I need these variables. Is there any good functions which can separate a string after the last space before the n'th symbol and put each line into a new variable.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your question is not clear and you show no code to start from.

Comment: Im looking for algorithm suggestions

Comment: But what is your question, that is not clear. Do you want an algorithm that understands the joke? or separate the text each 4 words?

Comment: The joke is just an example of a string, I want the program to do word wrap, but instead of saving the result in one variable, save each line to a new variable. I want each line to be no longer than lets say 30 symbols, but contain whole words.